# docker-compose build fail with file not found

Tags: docker, docker-compose, tomcat8

I would like to ask a question regarding the docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile.
Following is the situation I have met.

1. I first use **docker image build (docker image build -t test .)** and **docker run (docker run -p 8888:8080 -p 8889:8009 8883:8443 -v tomcat8:/usr/local/tomcat8 --name test test)** to test whether my Dockerfile is ready to go, and it is working.

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ENV HOME /usr/local/tomcat8

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install unzip wget openjdk-8-jdk

COPY ./installERDDAP.sh $HOME/installERDDAP.sh

COPY . $HOME/

RUN chmod +x $HOME/installERDDAP.sh

WORKDIR $HOME

RUN ./installERDDAP.sh

EXPOSE 8080 8443 8009

CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]
```

2. So that I script the docker-compose.yml, like below

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
   erddap:
      build:
         context: ./
         dockerfile: Dockerfile
      image: erddap_dev:2.02
      container_name: erddap
      restart: always
      ports:
         - "8888:8080"
         - "8883:8443"
         - "8889:8009"
      volumes:
         - ./tomcat8:/usr/local/tomcat8
```

3. However, the error message popup and said that the file **catalina.sh** does not exist. When I get into the container, well, that is true. There are no files existed. But if I put `RUN ls -la` in the **Dockerfile**, I do see the files are listed, like below.

```
Step 12/14 : RUN ls -la
 ---> Running in fed4870bd617
total 176
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  4096 Sep 11 20:08 .
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    21 Sep 11 20:08 ..
drwxrwxr-x. 8 root root   166 Sep 11 19:31 .git
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root root    12 Sep 11 07:50 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   165 Sep 11 20:08 .wget-hsts
-rw-r-----. 1 root root 19318 Jun 30 21:53 BUILDING.txt
-rw-r-----. 1 root root  5408 Jun 30 21:53 CONTRIBUTING.md
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root root   640 Sep 11 20:03 Dockerfile
-rw-r-----. 1 root root 57011 Jun 30 21:53 LICENSE
-rw-r-----. 1 root root  1726 Jun 30 21:53 NOTICE
-rw-r-----. 1 root root  3255 Jun 30 21:53 README.md
-rw-r-----. 1 root root  7136 Jun 30 21:53 RELEASE-NOTES
-rw-r-----. 1 root root 16262 Jun 30 21:53 RUNNING.txt
drwxr-x---. 2 root root  4096 Sep 11 20:08 bin
-rwxr-x---. 2 root root 25245 Jun 30 21:50 catalina.sh
drwx------. 2 root root   238 Jun 30 21:53 conf
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root    20 Sep 11 20:08 content
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root     6 Sep 11 20:08 data
drwxrwxr-x. 5 root root    44 Sep 11 03:46 doc
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root root   320 Sep 11 19:49 docker-compose.yml
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 root root  1030 Sep 11 19:41 installERDDAP.sh
drwxr-x---. 2 root root  4096 Sep 11 20:08 lib
drwxr-x---. 2 root root     6 Jun 30 21:49 logs
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    66 Sep 11 20:08 tarz
drwxr-x---. 2 root root    30 Sep 11 20:08 temp
drwxrwxr-x. 4 root root    29 Sep 11 19:41 tomcat8
drwxr-x---. 7 root root    99 Sep 11 20:08 webapps
drwxr-x---. 2 root root     6 Jun 30 21:49 work
Removing intermediate container fed4870bd617
```

Interestingly, these files are not also showing up in my volume directory. Could please someone tells me where am I wrong?

Thanks

---

1st Updates:

- According to the suggestion below, if I commended out the volumes within **docker-compose.yml** or if I added **WORKDIR /** in front of the CMD command, none of them are working.
- If I modified CMD commend in **Dockfile** from **CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]** to **CMD ["./catalina.sh","run"]** is not working, too. But if I changed to **CMD ["/usr/local/tomcat8/catalina.sh","run"]**, the build process is completed. But the errors than become

```
Attaching to erddap
erddap    | Cannot find /usr/local/bin/setclasspath.sh
erddap    | This file is needed to run this program
erddap    | Cannot find /usr/local/bin/setclasspath.sh
erddap    | This file is needed to run this program
erddap    | Cannot find /usr/local/bin/setclasspath.sh
erddap    | This file is needed to run this program
erddap    | Cannot find /usr/local/bin/setclasspath.sh
erddap    | This file is needed to run this program
erddap    | Cannot find /usr/local/bin/setclasspath.sh
erddap    | This file is needed to run this program
erddap    | Cannot find /usr/local/bin/setclasspath.sh
erddap    | This file is needed to run this program
erddap    | Cannot find /usr/local/bin/setclasspath.sh
erddap    | This file is needed to run this program
erddap    | Cannot find /usr/local/bin/setclasspath.sh
erddap    | This file is needed to run this program
erddap    | Cannot find /usr/local/bin/setclasspath.sh
erddap    | This file is needed to run this program
erddap    | Cannot find /usr/local/bin/setclasspath.sh
erddap    | This file is needed to run this program
```

2nd Updates:

installERDDAP.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir tarz

wget -q https://ftp.wayne.edu/apache/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.57/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.57.tar.gz -O ./tarz/apache-tomcat-8.5.57.tar.gz
tar -xf ./tarz/apache-tomcat-8.5.57.tar.gz -C /usr/local/tomcat8 --strip 1


mkdir data

ln ./bin/catalina.sh catalina.sh
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your docker file before the line `CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]` put `WORKDIR /` And change "catalina.sh" to "./catalina.sh"

Comment: cannot get the point why I should put WORKDIR / in front of the CMD commend. But it is failed still. The error is the same.

Comment: ERROR: for 2c10417f9d23_erddap  Cannot start service erddap: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"catalina.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Comment: ERROR: for erddap  Cannot start service erddap: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"catalina.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Comment: @FrankeHsu how about also change from "catalina.sh" to "./catalina.sh" inside CMD?

Comment: P.S. I guess I should use "/usr/local/tomcat/catalina.sh", although this is not making sense to me.  
Successfully built d4e32ab5e901
Successfully tagged erddap_dev:2.02
Recreating erddap ... done
Attaching to erddap
erddap    | Cannot find /usr/local/bin/setclasspath.sh
erddap    | This file is needed to run this program

Comment: If I combine both of your answers, then the server is working. Although I still cannot see my webapps from my host machine browsers.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell your bind mount may be "overriding/hiding" your container files. If your "./tomcat8" directory is not empty it will basically "override/hide" the files in your container.  I would remove the volume declaration to validate if this is the case, if so then you would need to clear out your "./tomcat8" directory and when you run the container again it should populate it with the files in the container, from then forward your local directory will again "override/hide" your container files.

Comment: Side note, you may have a reason for bind mounting the whole tomcat directory including binaries, but depending on what you want to do I would think you should be mounting the "conf" directory or the "webapps" directory instead.

Comment: I totally agreed with you, so that I have commented out the volumes in docker-compose.yml; however, I still get the error message like below.

Comment: WARNING: Image for service erddap was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
Creating erddap ... error

Comment: ERROR: for erddap  Cannot start service erddap: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"catalina.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Comment: Is there a specific reason you aren't using the tomcat official image? https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat

Comment: Can you post the content of installERDDAP.sh?

Comment: I was a FreeBSD user, so I like to learn things from blank. pull tomcat8 image doesn't help me to understand docker and docker-compose.

Comment: Your answer is correct. After I change my CMD to the full path, it is working. But now my app can only be detected in the container but cannot be browsing in my host machine.

Comment: I realized that actually my container is working well at midnight last night. As I mentioned above, I assign my port 8888:8080; however, when I open my browser and check http://localhost:8888/myapp, it will automatically switch to http://localhost:8080/myapp/index.html. This is the reason why I got the 404 message.